# Android: Where's the Memory Monitor tool?

Tags: android, memory

There is a tool Memory Monitor to analyze the memory allocation as time goes by, the figure it generates like below:

[image]

I just cannot find the tool like "Memory Monitor". Where can i find it?

Comment: I can't find it either.  It's just not where the doc say it should be.  It's not on the Tools->Android menu nor in the View->Tool Windows.   It's not on the button toolbar near the Gradle Console button.    This is a real problem.   Android Studio V1.2.1.1   Android SDK Tools 24.3.2.  Android SDK Platform-tools 22.

Comment: The new Android Profiler window in Android Studio 3.0 replaces the Android Monitor tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this tool location seems to have changed over time (as the Android Monitoring suite of tools grows), here's a breakdown for selected Android Studio versions (if you want to add a version that's missing, feel free to suggest an edit to this answer to include it!)

## Android Studio 2.2.3

IDE access (bottom left, now grouped with other monitors in the Monitor tab):

[image]

Menu access:

> View -> Tool Windows -> Android Monitor

## Android Studio 2.0 Preview

IDE access (bottom left):

[image]

Menu access:

> View -> Tool Windows -> Android Monitor

and then select the Memory tab.

## Android Studio 0.8.10

IDE access (bottom right):

[image]

Menu access:

> Tools -> Android -> Memory Monitor

or

> View -> Tool Windows -> Memory Monitor

Comment: Yeah, here's the Android Studio documentation on that feature: http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html#debug-perf I don't think it's a standalone tool. Check the other answer to this question for more detailed but less attractive alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Android Studio version (i'm using the [Canary](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary) channel) ver 1.3 the Memory Monitor is located under the Android tab at the bottom --> memory.

[image: Memory tool location]

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version (1.4.1) of Android Studio, it shows on the bottom, but you have to activate it, at least I needed to activate it by going to `Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration` as in the following image:

[image: ADB Integration menu]

I.e., there is no "Memory Tool" in the `Tools > Android` menu, as it is directly visible in the bottom left of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Android ships with a debugging tool called the Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS), which provides port-forwarding services, screen capture on the device, thread and heap information on the device, logcat, process, and radio state information, incoming call and SMS spoofing, location data spoofing, and more. This page provides a modest discussion of DDMS features; it is not an exhaustive exploration of all the features and capabilities.

**Viewing heap usage for a process**
DDMS allows you to view how much heap memory a process is using. This information is useful in tracking heap usage at a certain point of time during the execution of your application.

To view heap usage for a process:

In the Devices tab, select the process that you want to see the heap information for.
Click the Update Heap button to enable heap information for the process.
In the Heap tab, click Cause GC to invoke garbage collection, which enables the collection of heap data. When the operation completes, you will see a group of object types and the memory that has been allocated for each type. You can click Cause GC again to refresh the data.
Click on an object type in the list to see a bar graph that shows the number of objects allocated for a particular memory size in bytes.
[DDMS Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)